# Displaying styles stored in a GeoJson File and making lines appear as lines instead of markers

Tags: leaflet, styles, geojson, markers

I've been trying to get Leaflet to display a geojson file using the styles described in the geojson file, and I can't get it to work.  The geojson below shows that I've got styles in there - OGR style pen etc, but I've tried extracting them using style function(styles) {return {colour : data.properties.pen}}, but it gives me an error on the console - but not enough errors to match the number of layers - so I can understand that some layers may not have a "pen" property, but none of the layers are coming up with the any differences.

> "features": [
> { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "Buildings", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDb2dPolyline", "EntityHandle": "2ABF", "OGR_STYLE": "PEN(c:#ff7f00,p:"1.2g 0.72g 0.12g 0.72g")" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.386274792183286, 54.907452998026585, 0.0 ], [ -1.386201193400163,

In fact, as the above geojson shows, it's actually a geometry - but all that's showing up is a marker, which is my second problem.  Can anyone point me to some example codes or anything which may help me?

```
                $.getJSON(address, function(data) {
                //add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
                layer[i] = L.geoJson(data, {style: function(styles) {
                                              return {color: data.properties.pen,
                                                      weight: data.properites.weight
                                                    };
                                              onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                                                                      }
                                            }).addTo(map);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && layer instanceof L.Path) {
        layer.setStyle({
            color: feature.properties.pen,
            weight: feature.properites.weight
        });
    }
}


$.getJSON(address, function(data) {
    //add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
    layer[i] = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

[Leaflet GeoJson Tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)

Comment: Thank you.  I've put your code in - but I'm getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: layer.setStyle is not a function.  So I guessed that layer should be layer[i] - the array element for the layer, but then I get unexpected token [.  So I guess I can't pass the array into the function?

Comment: Then you have also points in your geojson, because a marker has not the function `.setStyle()`. I added to the if `&& layer instanceof L.Path` then it should work

Comment: Brill, that seems to work.  I'm seeing my geometries now, not in the correct styles - just the basic blues, but you've given me a good start to have a play around.  Thank you.

Comment: This is because you have no `pen` property, only the `OGR_STYLE` with the value `PEN(c:#ff7f00,p:"1.2g 0.72g 0.12g 0.72g")`. Please accept the answer if you think this has solved your problem